# INDEX, MATCH with IF

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to use an `INDEX` with `MATCH` that contains an `IF` expression.  
This previously worked in Excel 2010 but is no longer working in 2016. 
Any thoughts as to what is throwing the N/A error?

```
=INDEX(Staff[Lookup Office],MATCH(B49,Staff[Position Number],0))
```

I named a new table and the columns have updated from the old formula but even just swapping those it results in an `N/A` error. The above result works but I need the Lookup Office when the position number matches `AND` where `Staff[Incumbent]="Yes"` for `Staff[Position Number]`.  There will be 3+ results with a matching position number but only 1 has a "Yes" in the Incumbent column.

2010 Formula:

```
=INDEX(Table_owssvr[Full Name],MATCH("Yes",IF(Table_owssvr[Position Number]=C59,Table_owssvr[Incumbent]),0))
```

Comment: Hi, please edit your question. Format the code using backticks, or 4 spaces, and please review your sintax.

Comment: (1) It would help if you would show us some data and explain *exactly* what you are trying to do.  (2) What debugging have you done?  What do you get if you put ``=MATCH("Yes",IF(Table_owssvr[Position Number]=C59,Table_owssvr[Incumbent]),0)`` into a cell?  Have you tried doing what you want to do, but just using rows & columns instead of a table?

Comment: Also please try to evaluate your formula, it can help to find the problem.

Comment: Probably the formula would work if entered as array formula: press F2 to start editing it then press CTRL+SHIFT +ENTER

Comment: Mate thank you - I completely forgot about those even though the old ones had it.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is, why isn't the formula working?

### Here's why it doesn't work

`=INDEX(Table_owssvr[Full Name],MATCH("Yes",IF(Table_owssvr[Position Number]=C59,Table_owssvr[Incumbent]),0))`

[image: MATCH]

`MATCH` takes up to three arguments. For `lookup_value`, you have "Yes". OK.

For `lookup_array` which is for lack of a better term the 'place to look for' the lookup value, you have an `IF` statement. You haven't given the `IF` expression a `value_if_false` argument, which is fine for the `IF` statement. But when that statement - that is, `IF(Table_owssvr[Position Number]=C59` - isn't true, that expression evaluates to the logical value `FALSE`. And at that point, your `MATCH` function reads as follows:

`MATCH("Yes",FALSE,0)`

In other words you're looking for the string "Yes" in FALSE.

The result of that expression? `#N/A`.

### Recommended Further Reading

[image: Show Calculation Steps]